# Prevent products to be shipped to certain countries

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-address

Is there a way, in Magento 1.9.1 CE default, to prevent certain products to be shipped to certain countries? Or should I use some custom extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking what I think; you want to ship to, for example Canada, but certain products, such as from specific manufacturers can't be shipped to Canada.

You have to either rewrite the checkout process or get an extension. Amasty has one that worked well on one of my sites, but was around $100 - totally worth it to avoid me messing up the checkout.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any extension, I think most shipping method has ship to applicable countries, set it to Specific countries, then select countries. please check attached picture[image]

Comment: this will prevent all the products in my store to be shipped to the selected countries. What I need is to prevent only certain products to be shipped to certaion countries